# Merge a dataobj together using node.js

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

I have a MySQL call that returns data as an object however its looping over the object to edit the data. Imt ryign to figure out how to create one object with multiple sub datas.

The Current return data is belive, im trying to get it to be two array indexs groups on the eventid with the sub object(participants) to be multiple object data

Such as:

```
events[
    {
      ....
      ....
      participants: [
                     {...},
                     {...}
                    ]
    },
    {
       ....
    }

]
```

Current Data:

```
{
    "events": [
        {
            "eventid": 1,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Summer Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Denver, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "1000",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:4:57",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 4,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "57",
            "CountDownPercentage": 4,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "Billy",
                "lName": "Santos",
                "email": "billy.santos@gmail.com",
                "participantid": 1,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:49.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        },
        {
            "eventid": 1,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Summer Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Denver, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "1000",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:4:57",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 4,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "57",
            "CountDownPercentage": 4,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "Mary",
                "lName": "Sanchez",
                "email": "Mary.Sanchez@yahoo.com",
                "participantid": 2,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:52.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        },
        {
            "eventid": 1,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Summer Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Denver, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "1000",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:4:57",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 4,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "57",
            "CountDownPercentage": 4,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "John",
                "lName": "Egbert",
                "email": "john.egbert@test.com",
                "participantid": 3,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:54.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        },
        {
            "eventid": 1,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Summer Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Denver, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "1000",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:4:57",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 4,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "57",
            "CountDownPercentage": 4,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "arya",
                "lName": "stark",
                "email": "arya.stark@got.com",
                "participantid": 4,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:56.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        },
        {
            "eventid": 1,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Summer Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Denver, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "1000",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:4:57",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 4,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "57",
            "CountDownPercentage": 4,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "littlefinger",
                "lName": "balish",
                "email": "littlefinger.balish@got.com",
                "participantid": 5,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:59.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        },
        {
            "eventid": 2,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Winter Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-22T20:43:57.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Colorado Springs, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "800",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:20:44",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 20,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "44",
            "CountDownPercentage": 8,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "John",
                "lName": "Snow",
                "email": "John.Snow@got.com",
                "participantid": 6,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:30:02.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        },
        {
            "eventid": 2,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Winter Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-22T20:43:57.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Colorado Springs, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "800",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:20:44",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 20,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "44",
            "CountDownPercentage": 8,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "Cercey",
                "lName": "Lannister",
                "email": "Cercey.Lannister@got.com",
                "participantid": 7,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:30:04.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        },
        {
            "eventid": 2,
            "accountid": 1,
            "eventname": "Winter Camp",
            "eventstarts": "2017-09-22T20:43:57.000Z",
            "eventlocation": "Colorado Springs, CO",
            "eventparticipants": "800",
            "eventImg": "Image.png",
            "TimeTillStart": "3:20:44",
            "TimeTillStartDays": 3,
            "TimeTillStartHr": 20,
            "TimeTillStartMin": "44",
            "CountDownPercentage": 8,
            "participants": {
                "fName": "Danaryus",
                "lName": "Dragon",
                "email": "Danaryus.dragon@got.com",
                "participantid": 8,
                "applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:30:07.000Z",
                "IMG": "Image.png",
                "AGE": "28y"
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: You want to get an array with all the `participants`?

Comment: yeah its being returned int eh same query. Participants would be an array with multiple objects(each object being an participant)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [Array.prototype.map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map).

Code:

```js
const data = {"events": [{"eventid": 1,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Summer Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z","eventlocation": "Denver, CO","eventparticipants": "1000","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:4:57","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 4,"TimeTillStartMin": "57","CountDownPercentage": 4,"participants": {"fName": "Billy","lName": "Santos","email": "billy.santos@gmail.com","participantid": 1,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:49.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}},{"eventid": 1,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Summer Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z","eventlocation": "Denver, CO","eventparticipants": "1000","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:4:57","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 4,"TimeTillStartMin": "57","CountDownPercentage": 4,"participants": {"fName": "Mary","lName": "Sanchez","email": "Mary.Sanchez@yahoo.com","participantid": 2,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:52.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}},{"eventid": 1,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Summer Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z","eventlocation": "Denver, CO","eventparticipants": "1000","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:4:57","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 4,"TimeTillStartMin": "57","CountDownPercentage": 4,"participants": {"fName": "John","lName": "Egbert","email": "john.egbert@test.com","participantid": 3,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:54.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}},{"eventid": 1,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Summer Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z","eventlocation": "Denver, CO","eventparticipants": "1000","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:4:57","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 4,"TimeTillStartMin": "57","CountDownPercentage": 4,"participants": {"fName": "arya","lName": "stark","email": "arya.stark@got.com","participantid": 4,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:56.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}},{"eventid": 1,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Summer Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-08T04:57:36.000Z","eventlocation": "Denver, CO","eventparticipants": "1000","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:4:57","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 4,"TimeTillStartMin": "57","CountDownPercentage": 4,"participants": {"fName": "littlefinger","lName": "balish","email": "littlefinger.balish@got.com","participantid": 5,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:29:59.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}},{"eventid": 2,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Winter Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-22T20:43:57.000Z","eventlocation": "Colorado Springs, CO","eventparticipants": "800","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:20:44","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 20,"TimeTillStartMin": "44","CountDownPercentage": 8,"participants": {"fName": "John","lName": "Snow","email": "John.Snow@got.com","participantid": 6,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:30:02.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}},{"eventid": 2,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Winter Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-22T20:43:57.000Z","eventlocation": "Colorado Springs, CO","eventparticipants": "800","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:20:44","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 20,"TimeTillStartMin": "44","CountDownPercentage": 8,"participants": {"fName": "Cercey","lName": "Lannister","email": "Cercey.Lannister@got.com","participantid": 7,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:30:04.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}},{"eventid": 2,"accountid": 1,"eventname": "Winter Camp","eventstarts": "2017-09-22T20:43:57.000Z","eventlocation": "Colorado Springs, CO","eventparticipants": "800","eventImg": "Image.png","TimeTillStart": "3:20:44","TimeTillStartDays": 3,"TimeTillStartHr": 20,"TimeTillStartMin": "44","CountDownPercentage": 8,"participants": {"fName": "Danaryus","lName": "Dragon","email": "Danaryus.dragon@got.com","participantid": 8,"applicationTS": "2017-09-01T22:30:07.000Z","IMG": "Image.png","AGE": "28y"}}]};
const participants = data.events.map(evnt => evnt.participants);

console.log('participants:', participants);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Right but im trying to squish all the data together so each event would have its particular event data with a sub object of all the participants attending the event